# Visual Studio13 Creating Threads and Optimizing Process

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am writing multiple threads in VS13

Function declarations:

```
void getColorImage(HANDLE &colorEvent, HANDLE &colorStreamHandle, Mat &colorImage);
void getDepthImage(HANDLE &depthEvent, HANDLE &depthStreamHandle, Mat &depthImage);
void getSkeletonImage(HANDLE &skeletonEvent, Mat &skeletonImage, Mat &colorImage, Mat &depthImage, ofstream& myfile);

int main()
{
    // this is inside a while loop

    std::thread first(getColorImage, colorEvent, colorStreamHandle, colorImage);
    std::thread second(getDepthImage, depthEvent, depthStreamHandle, depthImage);
    std::thread third(getSkeletonImage, skeletonEvent, skeletonImage, colorImage, depthImage, myfile);

    first.join();
    second.join();
    third.join();
 }
```

However, I get an error:

> Error  1   error C2280: 'std::basic_ofstream>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits  1545    1   Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013

Don't know why... can someone please help?

Comment: Use `std::ref(myfile)` instead of  just `myfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread` constructor, the same as `std::bind`, takes all its parameters by value. But `std::ofstream` have a `delete`d copy constructor, hence the error.

Wrap all parameters that should be passed by reference with `std::ref`.

Comment: That worked thanks!
I am also saving images within the while loop after this, and I'm trying to speed that up too.

  std::thread im01(cv::imwrite, fnameC, colorImage);
  std::thread im02(cv::imwrite, fnameD, depthImage);

  im01.join();
  im02.join();



But get an error: Error 1 error C2198: 'bool (__cdecl *)(const std::string &,cv::InputArray,const std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : too few arguments for call c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional 1149 1 Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ajl123: The error message is crystal clear: you left out an argument.

Comment: However, cv::imwrite takes two arguments. a file name and a Mat image, which I am passing?

Comment: @ajl123: The error message clearly shows that there is a third argument of type `const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &`. It is actually an optional argument, but I guess you cannot omit it in templated code.

Comment: @ajl123: `std::thread` follows the syntax of `std::bind`, which is weird. It is easier to pass a lambda, like `std::thread something([=](){cv::imwrite(fnname, image);});`.